# Error 404.4 when trying to open an html file from asp file

Tags: html, iis, windows-7, asp-classic

I have been working on a project to create a payroll management system. I have the following issue:
When i try to create a link within an asp file e.g.

```
.
.
if Found = 1 then
response.write("Welcome " & rec("firstname") & " " & rec("lastname"))
%>

<br><a href="admin_home.html">Click to continue....</a>

<%      
else
%>
.
.
```

i keep getting the following error when i click on the link:

```
HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.



Module  IIS Web Core
Notification    MapRequestHandler
Handler Not yet determined
Error Code  0x80070002
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/Project/Home.html
Physical Path   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Project\Home.html
Logon Method    Anonymous
Logon User  Anonymous
```

The same problem with other links to html files via ASP files. Please advice.

Comment: Which IIS version? On a server or local on your Windows 7 box?

Comment: local on your Windows 7 box. IIS 7.5

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have installed aps module and asp files are running fine. In that case, you haven't configured static file handler in your IIS's web.config.

Configuration >> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771240(v=ws.10).aspx

Regards,

Comment: all the modules and asp files seem to be working fine. what am i supposed to add in the staticHandler for html files ?

Comment: Can you check whether these 3 modules StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule are enabled ? These are the modules which handle static content.

Comment: yes they are. request path set to *
Within request restrictions,
Mapping to file or folder
Verbs to all verbs
Access to read

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Try path = *.html in the config.

Comment: Tried.still the same issue.

Comment: Can you please post your static handler config part ? Thanks,